# the docker container `heroku run` command with arguments returns "not found"

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm running a docker container on heroku, but I can't seem to understand how it works.

Locally I'm able to run a command `docker run imageName ls -al`, but on heroku: `heroku run "ls -al"` it returns `./entrypoint.sh: line 34: exec: ls -al: not found`. Although when I run `heroku run ls` without arguments, it works as expected. (as another experiment I've run `heroku run bash` and then `./entrypoint.sh ls -al` that also works).

What's happening here?

#### Comments updates:

- Damien MATHIEU: the image I try to run is this https://github.com/jshimko/meteor-launchpad - and my docker file is:

  ```
  FROM jshimko/meteor-launchpad:latest 
  CMD ["node", "main.js"]
  ```

Comment: Could you paste the content of your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit-2 - 28-Oct-2017**

Latest update from Heroku

> We've triaged this, and we're definitely not implementing Docker-compatible behaviour here. Thanks for catching this - we'll get it fixed.

**Original answer**

Your error is quite clear from below itself

```
./entrypoint.sh: line 34: exec: ls -al: not found
```

You are passing `ls -al` as one string parameter. You should try below

```
heroku run -- ls -al
```

**Edit-1**

So I created a simple `Dockerfile` to test the issue.

```
FROM alpine
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

And the `entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "You passed $# arguments"
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done

exec "$@"
```

When I build and run the container locally I get the output as

```
$ docker run -it 5e866a76fd25
You passed 3 arguments
tail
-f
/dev/null
```

When I push the app to Heroku I get below output on logs

```
2017-10-21T19:11:11.873567+00:00 app[api]: Deployed web (xxxxx) by user xxx@yyy.com
2017-10-21T19:11:14.235819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `tail -f /dev/null`
2017-10-21T19:11:16.593724+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2017-10-21T19:11:16.447960+00:00 app[web.1]: You passed 1 arguments
2017-10-21T19:11:16.447976+00:00 app[web.1]: tail -f /dev/null
```

This is completely wrong, as the CMD is being sent quoted as a single argument instead of the 3 arguments. I have opened a ticket for the same with heroku team, hopefully they will reply before Tue

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. This runs the same command and has the same output http://prntscr.com/h07y1m

Comment: Let me check something and get back to you

Comment: @Merstzik, its a issue with Heroku, updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm also running into this issue. As a temporary workaround, I've put my original `CMD` into a separate script file, and now calling that script file in `CMD`.

Here's my original `Dockerfile`:

```
...
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
```

Here's my *new* `Dockerfile`:

```
...
RUN chmod +x PATH_TO_START_SCRIPT/start.sh
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

And my `start.sh` script (starting a Rails app):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "Starting Puma server..."

bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```